# CheckStyle, FindBugs, and PMD configurations without overlap

Tags: java, findbugs, checkstyle, pmd

At my company we started using CheckStyle, FindBugs, and PMD to check our code quality and unify our programming styles. These tools are very effective but unfortunately they have some overlapping rule sets.

**Are there configurations available online which have removed the overlapping rules?**

Of course, these default rule sets are not applicable to every project but it would be a good starting point for us. We could take this default (non overlapping) configuration and adapt it to our style instead of pruning the rule sets for duplicates first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) ships with some pretty good configurations called *Sonar Way* and *Sonar Way with FindBugs* which don't appear to have any overlap between the different tools (CheckStyle, FindBugs, and PMD). They seem to fulfill my needs as a decent starting point for a configuration without all the superfluous rules.

PS I was hesitant to answer my own question but nobody else had an answer or even an insightful comment. [This thread on Meta also seems to think it's okay.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

Comment: I agree, Sonar is a nice choice.

Comment: Sonar way with FindBugs is the best! Specially if you are looking for opnesource solutions in this space.

Comment: By the way in latest SonarQube 4.5.1 there is no quality profile by the name 'Sonar Way with FindBugs'. The available quality profiles are 'Sonar Way' and 'FindBugs'